# Find cosets of $H$ in $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

> Let $G$ = $\operatorname{Sym}(\{1,2,3,4\})$ and let $ H = ⟨(1,2,3,4),(2,4)⟩$. Write out all the cosets of $H$ in $G$

So, I know that $G$ contains $4!= 24$ elements, because it's the permutation group. 
I don't understand how to get the generated group $H$, so my first question is: Is $H$ a group generated by 2 elements?, the next question is: How to get that group ( I saw in another question that $H=⟨(1,2)⟩=\{(1,2),(2,4),(0,0)\}$, I think that it depends based in the group operation).

My first approach to solve the problem is find the $H$ group and then, I can find the cosets (and that is another problem: How to define that coset) of $H$.

So, thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: You want the smallest group containing those elements. How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $H=<\alpha,\beta>$ and $|\alpha|=4 ,|\beta|=2$ then $H=\{(\alpha^4=) I,
\alpha, \alpha ^2 ,\alpha ^3, \beta , \alpha \beta , \alpha ^2\beta , \alpha^3 \beta \}.$
This is how you compute the subgroup generated by two elements $\alpha $ and $\beta$.

**EDIT :**
*In generally* if $H = <\alpha, \beta>$ and $\alpha, \beta$ do not have any numbers in common i.e. disjoint cycles then $\alpha^m\beta^n = \beta^n\alpha^m$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, because disjoint cycles commute. Therefore in that case $\{\alpha^m\beta^n : m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is the complete list of elements of $H$.

However, if the cycles aren't disjoint then we need to compute products of the form $\beta^j\alpha^i$, $\alpha^i\beta^j\alpha^k$, $\beta^i\alpha^j\beta^k\alpha^l$,... etc and develop a relation like $\alpha^s\beta^r= \beta^t\alpha^u$ etc. for some $r,s,t,u \in \mathbb{Z}$ and use *Lagrange's theorem* to get the order of the subgroup because in generally $\beta^j\alpha^i$ may be distinct from the elements listed above.

Now, in this example the cycles are not disjoint. So I computed  some other elements, basically $\beta\alpha, \beta\alpha^2, \beta \alpha^3$ and found the relations $\beta\alpha=\alpha^3 \beta , \beta\alpha^2 = \alpha ^2\beta,
\beta \alpha^3= \alpha \beta$. And since $|\alpha|=4 ,|\beta|=2$, using associative property and the relations we can compute any combination of products of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and see that they all belong to the complete list that I stated for $H$.

Comment: Any reference to get that? (Such a book, post, etc ...)

Comment: Look that's my insight from reading and understanding. But I'll let you here if I find anything like this in a book that I have. But let me help you understanding it....if H is generated by two finitely ordered elements (the case that you're facing in your question) then it actually means $H=<a,b> = \{a^mb^n : m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ and this means that you've to consider all possible combinations of the elements $a$ and $b$. Although the computation is same when the elements are of infinite order, it's just in that case $H$ will be infinite.

Comment: It's same as the case when $H=<a>$ i.e generated by single element, where you compute $H$ by considering all possible powers of $a$ and then determining which are distinct (in the case where order of $a$ is finite).

Comment: Thanks, I get that, I have another question, and it's: How to compute for example $\alpha \beta$ in this case ( (1,2,3,4) * (2,4)), What is the operation * ?

Comment: It's simple. The main thing that you need to keep in mind is that the multiplication is done through composition of functions. Always multiply taking an element from the right most cycle. In this case see that in the right most cycle sends $1\to 1$ and the left cycle sends $1 \to 2$. So in the first case $f(1)=1$ and in the second case $g(f(1))=g(1)=2$. Therefore in the product cycle you'll have $1 \to 2$. Then take what you got as the last image, in this case it's $2$ and see where it ends up getting mapped just like in a similar method.

Comment: This answer is wrong in general. A group generated by an element of order $4$ and an element of order $2$ can have more than $8$ elements. For example, $S_4$ is generated by $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(1,2)$.

Comment: Since both cycles are not disjoint, you have to check the cases $\beta\alpha^{i}$

Comment: @Liddo you're right. I'll edit the answer and let you know why I just let the subgroup be like that and explain further things. I'll do it as soon as I can write it here.